# Tutorial on Meteor Website not working

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to do the tutorial from the meteor site but the moving between pages is not working. For example the ToDo App tutorial, clicking on any of the sections 2 to 12 does not open the instructions for that section. It just stays on the first section. Thought the address bar changes. I've tried on multiple browsers but on one PC.

Comment: Which browser are you using? In case you're firing the page movement based on some event, try adding an ```event.preventDefault()``` first, then route to the page you would like to go.

Comment: I'm using chrome and tried firefox. I'm talking about the actual tutorial. Like the first section is "1. Creating an App" and then if i click 'Next', the address bar changes, but the page stays exactly the same, except that the nav on the sidebar makes the next section active. So it shows "2. Templates" as being active, but its the content for Section 1 on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It's working now :) Eish we are so entitled, a free service stops working properly for a little and we go crazy.